# calling super init method without arguments

Tags: python, class, init, super

I have a questio about `super().__init__()` method. According to W3SCHOOLS the definition and usage (of super) is:

- The `super()` function is used to give access to methods and properties of a parent or sibling class.
- The `super()` function returns an object that represents the parent class.

However i really can't understand why and where can we use `super().__init__()` method without any argument in `__init__` (since, even without `super`, the `__init__` method of the parent class is called as soon as we insert the name of the parent's class on the parenthesis).

I AM NEW TO Objected Oriented programming so i am just trying to understand how it works!!!

To help you understand my problem see the example below:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width

    def area1(self):
        return self.length * self.width

class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, length):
        super().__init__(length, length)

square = Square(4)
square.area()
```

Here we use it because we need to define the `self.length, self.width` on the Rectangle class 
(we insert length, length).

However i don't know why we use it without any arguments like in the next example. 
Since i know that we can access the methods and attributes of a parent class without the need to call the super.

```
class Example(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
                
        self.lineEntry = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEntry.move(16,16)
        self.lineEntry.resize(200,40)
  
        self.setGeometry(50,50,320,200)
        self.setWindowTitle("QLineEdit Example")
        self.show()
        

        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        ex = Example()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You need to pass arguments if the parent class's `__init__()` method has required arguments. It's no different from calling any other function or method.

Comment: "According to W3SCHOOLS" just a heads up, that isn't the greatest resource. Generally better to reference [the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)

Answer (score 2):

Not every attribute is passed to the constructor - some may be private attributes that have default values assigned in the constructor. Additionally, the parent class's constructor may do things other than just assigning attributes, such as setting up a cache. Without the `super().__init__()`, they won't run.

Comment: yeah but why do people say that  super helps you, access the methods and attributes of a parent calss? I say that because you can access them even without using it!! for example could you please look at this code i created? https://www.codepile.net/pile/xyQew9yk

Comment: That's because if you don't provide a `__init__`, its inherited from the parent and the parent's `__init__` is called, which is why that example works. However, if you override `__init__` in a subclass, then `animal`'s `__init__` won't be called.

Comment: w3schools's tutorials are of very questionable quality, so I can see how their definition is confusing.

Comment: [Example](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzknsbhYISCxKDWvxIpLAQhSUtMU4uMz8zJL4uM1ilNz0jQh4iBQUJSZV6KhVABWDlelpMkFMcY5IzMnxVADYhpUWwFQAlnaCFWaCNuSwdqQbYNIQG3TROEbAfn//wMA "Python 3 – Try It Online")